# Gaussian elimination issue in solving the matrix

Tags: c++, gaussian

```
float aMatrix[10][11];
float bMatrix[10];
```

// called as such...
    `solveMatrix(aMatrix, bMatrix, actualCol);`

```
float* solveMatrix(float aMatrix[][DEFCOLS+1],float bMatrix[DEFCOLS], size_t cols){
    std::cout << "\nInside solveMatrix...: " << endl;
    size_t N2 = cols;

std::cout << "\N2 is...: " << N2 << endl;
for(size_t p=0; p<N2; p++){
    //std::cout << "\nInside 1st for loop...: " << endl;
    // find pivot row and swap
    int max = p;

    for(size_t i=p+1; i<N2; i++){
        //std::cout << "\nInside 2nd for loop...: " << endl;
        if ( abs(aMatrix[i][p]) > abs(aMatrix[max][p]) ){
            max = i;
        }
    }

    //std::cout << "\nJust b4 all the swapping...: " << endl;

    float temp[] = { *aMatrix[p] };
    *aMatrix[p] = *aMatrix[max];

    *aMatrix[max] = *temp;

    float t = bMatrix[p];
    bMatrix[p] = bMatrix[max];


    bMatrix[max] = t;
    //std::cout << "\nDone all the swapping...: " << endl;

    if ( abs(aMatrix[p][p]) <= MINISCULE) {
        //std::cout << "***** Error matrix value too small. Matrix is singular" << endl;
        //exit;
    }

    //std::cout << "\nJust the pivoting...: " << endl;

    // Pivot /in A and b
    for(size_t i=p+1; i<N2; i++){
        //std::cout << "\nInside the 1st pivoting loop...: " << endl;

        //std::cout << "\nAbout to do the  [aMatrix[p][p]] division in back subst..: " << endl;
        float alpha = aMatrix[i][p] / aMatrix[p][p];

        bMatrix[i] = alpha * bMatrix[p];

        for(size_t j=p; j<N2; j++){
            //std::cout << "\nInside the 2nd pivoting loop...: " << endl;
            aMatrix[i][j] -= alpha * aMatrix[p][j];
        }

    }
    std::cout << "\nAbout to do the back subst..: " << endl;
    // back subst.
    float outMatrix[DEFROWS] = {0.0};

    for(size_t i=N2-1; i>=0; i--){
        std::cout << "\nInside the 1st back subst for loop..: " << endl;
        float sum = 0.0;

        for(size_t j=i+1; j<N2; j++){
            std::cout << "\nInside the 2nd back subst for loop..: " << endl;
            sum += aMatrix[i][j] * outMatrix[j];
        }

        std::cout << "\nAbout to do the [aMatrix[i][i]] division in back subst..: " << endl;

            std::cout << "\n*outMatrix[i]: " << outMatrix[i] << endl;
            std::cout << "\n( bMatrix[i] - sum ) : " << ( bMatrix[i] - sum )  << endl;
            std::cout << "\n****aMatrix[i][i] : " << aMatrix[i][i]  << endl;            

        if (aMatrix[i][i] > 0){
            std::cout << "\nDid the division [aMatrix[i][i]] > 0 division in back subst..: " << endl;
            std::cout << "\n*outMatrix[i]: " << outMatrix[i] << endl;
            std::cout << "\n( bMatrix[i] - sum ) : " << ( bMatrix[i] - sum )  << endl;
            std::cout << "\naMatrix[i][i] : " << aMatrix[i][i]  << endl;

            outMatrix[i] =  ( bMatrix[i] - sum ) / aMatrix[i][i];

            std::cout << "\nDid the division [aMatrix[i][i]] > 0 division in back subst..DONE: " << endl;

        }else {
            std::cout << "\nDid the divirion [aMatrix[i][i]] = 0 division in back subst..: " << endl;
            outMatrix[i] = 0.0;
            std::cout << "\nDid the divirion [aMatrix[i][i]] = 0 division in back subst..DONE: " << endl;
        }

        std::cout << "\nDid the [aMatrix[i][i]] division in back subst..: " << endl;
    }

    std::cout << "\nLeft the back subst for loops..: " << endl;

    return outMatrix;
}  
}  // end solveMatrix()
```

My problem is that my program seems to run but seems to run past the end of the matrix and crashes.  Plus I am getting some large exponential numbers and the largest numbers that I have in the array is from 1-10.

here is a screenshot of the output:  Can't seem to paste from the snipping tool. But the problem seem to start after the "back substitution" starts.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Obviously you can't paste from snipping tool. Save the image on disk, then choose "Insert an image" > "From computer" > "Browse"

Comment: Consider using LAPACK for this.

Comment: @DeepYellow: For the most part if you're doing a full blown numerical simulation, I'd agree. But if you're trying to learn about this or if you need it for one really specialized case I'd disagree. LAPACK can be a bit much for a small project.

Comment: @MikeBantegui: Hence the word "consider". :-) But to your "specialized case" comment, the OP isn't handling a special case, he's doing a general solve.  Would you be worried about the footprint?  Statically linked LAPACK can be very compact.  It would also be MUCH more efficient than the OP's code, since with an appropriate BLAS (e.g. MKL) it will be highly optimized for the hardware including multi-threading.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what all the problems are, but one clear issue is your `outMatrix`. You are returning a pointer to a local array. The array is being destroyed at the end of the function. The pointer you are returning is now junk.

Change this line:

```
float outMatrix[DEFROWS] = {0.0};
```

To:

```
float* outMatrix = new float[DEFROWS];
```

Then you need to zero that out.

**NOTE:** It would be better if you used a `vector<float>` and returned that, but you wrote it with a raw pointer so I am answering with raw pointer.  Raw pointers lead to memory leaks. They should be avoided when possible.  With modern C++ it is rarely necessary to allocate a raw pointer.

EDIT:
See [Effective C++ Item #31](http://iskren.info/reading/info/C++/effective%20c++/EC/EI31_FR.HTM)

EDIT2: Changing to use vector, if your compiler supports the move operators and constructors as defined in the C++11 standard, then returning a vector is a cheap operation.

```
std::vector<float> solveMatrix(/* Your arguments */)
{

    std::vector<float> outMatrix(DEFROWS, 0.0);

    // Your code

    return outMatrix;
}
```

Comment: I took your suggestion and used a vector vice a matrix and things are looking a bit better however the program will not enter the second for loop after the vector is declared. I ran it through the debugger and what I noticed is that the i,j variables are always some large number 8-digits even though I init them to 0??!! Any ideas would be helpful - Thanks.

Comment: @MichealNoel - What is the value of `cols` that is being passed in. You set `N2 = cols` at the top of the function. Then you set `i = N2` and `j = i + 1`. If N2 is being set with a junk value then you can have those issues.

Comment: @MichealNoel - Any update on this? I was not sure what values you are using for `DEFROWS` and `DEFCOLS`, nor what value you are passing in to the method for `cols`, with those I could run through what you have and then suggest other improvements.